# Latin nouns derived from pluperfect verbs

Tags: grammar, latin, derivation, gerund

I am trying to understand the logic of Latin nouns derived from pluperfect verbs. For example, we have *facta*, things done, and *scripta*, things written, but I thought the pluperfect gerundive would be something like *scribenda*, things having been written. What exactly is the syntactical logic behind Latin pluperfect gerundives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of confusion here... Let's try to clear it up:

Forms like *facta, scripta* are neuter plural forms of the perfect passive participle. The meaning of the perfect passive participle is "having been (verb)ed", so *factus, -a, -um* means "having been done"; *factum* as a neuter used nominally means "thing having been done, thing done", and *facta* is the plural of this.

The gerundive, a.k.a. future passive participle, is something completely different. Its meaning is "that will be (verb)ed" or more often "needing/deserving/etc. to be (verb)ed". So *scribendus, -a, -um* means "(something) to be written", and *scribenda* are "things to be written*.

The pluperfect plays no part here at all: neither of these are derived from the pluperfect, and there's no pluperfect gerundive.

Answer (score 1):

Facta and scripta are perfect passive participles in the neuter plural. They are not pluperfect.